# Is there a javascript module to format user text input into proper "english" format?

Tags: javascript, html, text, converters, user-input

I am looking for a text formatter that will take user input from a textbox and add in newlines and stuff.

The current way I'm doing it is to push the text into a function and replace specific regex matches with their html counterparts:

```
function textformatter(text) {  
                    var urlRegex =/[\n\r]/g;
                    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(text) {
                        return '<br/>';
                    });
}
```

I'd have to add a new regex match for each thing I want to replace i.e. italics, bolds, etc. Thought I'd try to find a module out there because this seems like a common thing to do and someone might've written something much better than what I'd write.

Tried to google but I guess my search words are incorrect?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: See [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear what you want the intended output to be? ("add in newlines and stuff"), but have you looked at [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)?

It's a light-weight markup language lets you write mostly in plain text and get formatted html as an output. All the markup is supposed to be plain-text readable (for example, bold is done with asterisks). In fact, StackOverflow comments/answers/questions are written in a markdown dialect! And you'll definitely be able to find a markdown converter for whatever language you want. Here's a [js markdown parser](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js).

In any case, it's hard to answer without knowing more about what you need. What is `text` in the function you're calling? Is it plain text from a `textarea`? Besides replacing new lines with `<br>`, what formatting do you want to be done?

Comment: 'markdown' was the term I needed. The one you linked looks good! I'll try it out but now I'll be able to google better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Markdown would be the right thing to use for text, but if you simply want to escape unsafe characters, the javascript method encodeURIComponent could be used.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp